# AngularJS / UI Router - Locale in State URL / TemplateURL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

What I'm trying to accomplish is to set a `$scope` variable to the state parameters,

```
  .state('form', {
        url: '/' + locale + '/form',
        templateUrl: locale + '/form.html',
        controller: 'formController'
    })
```

Currently I'm just using a variable

```
var locale
```

However I want the URL's to dynamically change if the

```
$scope.locale
```

changes. For example, if the user selects English, then the scope will change to

```
$scope.locale = 'en';
```

I want this to also reflect in the states / URL, and bring the user to the appropriate language page. I guess I'm trying to do something like this:

```
  .state('form', {
        url: '/' + $scope.locale + '/form',
        templateUrl: $scope.locale + '/form.html',
        controller: 'formController'
    })
```

Is there any way to live-update this `$scope` information in the `$stateParams`??

How can I accomplish a live change in both templateUrl as well as URL of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do that by specifying parameters in the url, and templateUrl a function with injected $stateParams:

```
  .state('form', {
        url: '/:locale/form',
        templateUrl: function($stateParams) { return $stateParams.locale + '/form.html' },
        controller: 'formController'
    })
```